# is it possible to create firestore collections/documents through firebase CLI?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to create some documents inside firestore through firebase CLI.
I know we can define custom indexes locally and then deploy them but I'm wondering if we can also populate them with some initial data.

Answer (score 3):

The only Firestore command we can find in the [Firebase CLI documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands) is the `firestore:delete` command, to be used for "deleteing documents in the active project's database".

---

On the other hand, you can easily write your own "admin" code to populate your Firestore database, using one of the numerous languages available with the Admin SDKs (Java, Python, C++, Ruby, C#, Node.js, ... ) or with the Client SDKs (Web, Android, iOS).